# Xamarin - SignalR Hanging on connect

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, signalr

I'm trying to connect my Xamarin app to my SignalR backend which is hosted on Azure. The issue I'm having is every time I call StartAsync() on my HubConnection it just hangs the client and the request is never completed.

I have tried break pointing through the app to make sure this is actually where the hang is happening. I have tried using the exact same code on an ASP.Net Core project to confirm the SignalR connection is working, which it is, I can connect and send commands successfully. I have tried on IOS and Android both simulators and real devices and the same issue each time. Every time I hit the StartAsync the app just hangs. Each project has the latest Xamarin and Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client Nuget installed.

```
HubConnection connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl("URLFORCHAT")
                .Build();

await connection.StartAsync();
```

The expected result is for the client to just connect and continue through the program just like the ASP.Net Core project does. I have seen other tutorials that have the same code as me and it is in fact working.

Comment: Are you making any blocking calls `.Result` or `.Wait()` that could be causing a deadlock?

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks for the reply, No I'm not, however after more testing I have found moving the whole section out of the constructor makes the code work. Which is a good start but strange it doesn't work. I can work around this for now.

Comment: I am having the same issue in IIS.  I have a .NET Core Console app that calls StartAsync and runs fine, but when I run the signalr client code out of IIS (exact same code), it hangs StartAsync.  It seems like a bug, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @mikegold Dude you just explained my problem. It doesn't work when hosted in IIS. Not sure why though, still trying to find out.